# Does Raspberry Pi 4 supports pointer authentication?

Tags: pi-4, security, arm

I know that ARM Pointer Authentication feature is supported on all ARMv8.3-A processors, and this version was presented at 10/2016. RPi 4 Model B was released last year so there is a good chance the version of the SoC processor supports this feature, but in all the specs I found the processor version is just ARMv8-A, without mentioning the sub-section.

I'm a Software Security researcher, and I'm looking specifically for the Pointer Authentication feature so it's important to me to confirm its exists. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The syntax for using this feature is described in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: If you know any command to check it, I'll be more than happy to help you.

Comment: Thanks. According to https://lwn.net/Articles/718888/ the relevant instructions are `PAC` and `AUT` to calculate the authentication code and to authenticate it (respectively).

Comment: I just edited the post and gave example from ARM guide: https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/slides/slides_23.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Raspberry Pi documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711/README.md), the RPi 4B uses a Cortex A72, which was released in [2016](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-A72). According to [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_ARMv8-A_cores), it is based on ARMv8.0-A, so it should not include your feature. In fact, no core released by ARM directly supports ARMv8.3‑A.

Comment: Thanks. maybe no ARM core is exactly 8.3-A, but there are cores in the wild that support this feature, e.g. new iPhone devices.

Comment: The announced Arm Cortex-A78C core supports PAC and extended PAC (from ARMv8.6-A): https://developer.arm.com/ip-products/processors/cortex-a/cortex-a78c (NB: the Cortex-A78AE and the older Cortex-A78 do not).

Answer (score 3):

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2002.07936.pdf) mentions there is no open and public board that supports PAC instructions. iPhone A12 is the only option that is proprietary.   Therefore, the paper has simulated some instructions and tested on Raspberry Pi 4.